# Statements on Cardinality of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Which of the statements regarding cardinality of sets are always correct

Let $X$ be an infinite set then

(1)$|\{F|F \subseteq X  \;\text {and} \;X \; \text {is finite}\}| > $|X|$

(2) $A \in P(X) $ and $ X\setminus A $ is infinite $\rightarrow |A|<|X|$

(3) $A \subseteq X $ and $|A|<|X| \Rightarrow  |X\setminus A|=|X|$

(4)$|X|<|P(X)|$

(5) $|X*X|>|X|$

and $P(X)$ indicates the power set of X. I think 4 is correct but I am not sure of the rest please provide help since we have not been covered cardinality in the course properly

Comment: In the future, please post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be closed, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one?).

Comment: For #2, consider "nice" uncountable subsets of the reals. To answer #5, we need more information (in particular, what axioms are you working with?) #3 has been answered on this site before, and I suspect that #1 has, as well.

Comment: Are you assuming the axiom of choice?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Yes I am

Comment: (3) is the only statement whose truth value could change in the absence of choice. (It is always true under choice, and there are models where choice fails, and there are counterexamples.)

Comment: @Andres: (3) provably fails when choice fails. Take $A$ to be non-well orderable, and take $X=A+\aleph(A)$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about (4): this is [Cantor’s theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem), a very important basic result about cardinalities. Assuming the axiom of choice, (5) is false: it is a general fact about infinite sets that $|X\times X|=|X|$. Unless you’re taking a course that goes into well-orderings in some detail, you could not reasonably be asked to prove this; I imagine that you’re simply expected to learn it as a fact. The same goes for (1): if $X$ is an infinite set, and $\mathscr{F}$ is the set of finite subsets of $X$, then $|\mathscr{F}|=|X|$. (3), on the other hand, is true; again, this is probably something that you’re expected simply to learn as a fact, unless you’re taking a fairly serious elementary set theory course.

Syd Henderson has given a nice, straightforward example showing that (2) is not necessarily true.

Comment: @user14111: True, and I didn’t say otherwise: it’s the general fact that is beyond the scope of a really elementary course.

Answer (score 3):

To see #2 is false, let X be the set of integers and A the set of odd integers. Then X, A and X\A all have the same cardinality.